# Cross Platform Button Ordering in Java and Swing

Tags: java, netbeans, cross-platform

I'm creating a cross platform application using Swing and Netbeans (Group Layout). Is there a trick I am missing to help develop dialogs with say OK, Cancel buttons in the correct order for different platforms - specifically Windows (OK-Cancel) and Mac (Cancel-OK), rather like the `JOptionPane` does?  I can derive my own class from `JDialog` with two buttons on it, and swap text and actions around - I just wondered if there is something 'out of the box' I've missed. (This is *not* a question about which way round buttons should be, or the use of verbs e.g. Save instead of Ok.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MiGLayout](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/) supports this out of the box. Either use this layout manager, or look how it does its magic.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse SWT also provides platform-aware layouts.